# How to calculate point of Elliptical Arc

Tags: math, geometry

I want to calculate points of elliptical arc. I knwo coordinates of start point, end point, center of ellipse, radian for x and y, i know angle of x rotate, i know angles beetwen end point and center, and start point and center.

I have problem with calculate points and rotate them.

I use euqation:

x = rx * cos(alfa)
y = ry * sin(alfa)

[resultx, resulty] = ([x,y] * rotatex) + [cx,cy] - rotate and translate with cx,cy (center of ellipse)

The main problem is, that start point and end point is rotated too, but these points should be static (without rotate). I don't know how to inlcude this case.

Now i get points for rotated ellpitical arc, but my start point and end point are also rotated.

Comment: `How to calculate point of Elliptical Arc?` and `How to calculate rotations?` are two different questions that seems intermixed in your post. Please edit it and clarify

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but I think this is what you want:

```
x = rx * cos(alfa-beta)
y = ry * sin(alfa-beta)

[resultx, resulty] = ([x,y] * rotatex(beta)) + [cx,cy]
```